# An elementary question about rectangles covering a rectangle

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

While reading up on measure theory in the book by Cohn, I stumbled upon the following fact that should be elementary to prove. Let $K \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a compact rectangle (a rectangle is by definition a product of intervals), and let $R_1,..,R_n$ be open rectangles such that

$$K \subset \cup_i R_i.$$

Prove that $$\text{vol}(K) \leq \sum_i \text{vol}(R_i),$$
where by the “vol” of a rectangle we mean the product of the lengths of its sides.
Note that lebesgue measure is not defined at this point yet. I’m looking for an elementary yet rigorous proof of this fact. What I came up with so far was: if the above inclusion holds then of course we have the following inequality of characteristic functions
$$1_K \leq \sum_i 1_{R_i}.$$
Taking Riemann-integral on both sides and using linearity of the integral gives the result. But this seems somewhat of an overkill. Any ideas?

Comment: What is VOL here if it isn't Lesbegues mesure ? What kind of mesure it is ?

Comment: @EDX the volume of a rectangle is defined to be the product of its sides

Comment: Sort of making the Riemann integral argument "by hand": You can use the set of endpoints of each of the $R_i$ rectangles in each dimension to form a grid of smaller (not necessarily open) pairwise disjoint rectangles $S_j$ such that each $R_i$ is a finite union of $S_j$'s. Then $K \subseteq \cup R_i = \cup S_j$, so $\operatorname{vol}(K) \leq \operatorname{vol}(\cup S_j) = \sum \operatorname{vol}(S_j) \leq \sum \operatorname{vol}(R_i)$. Writing out all the details is straightforward but a bit annoying, hence I'm only commenting instead of answering. :-D

Comment: Btw, using the Riemann integral argument might be circular if the proof of the linearity of the integral relies on a similar decomposition of rectangles when forming a common partition.

Comment: @Bungo
It's precisely this writing out of the details what I'm asking for

Comment: It's laborious to type out, I doubt that anyone is going to want to do it, but hopefully I'm wrong and you'll get a full answer. If not, you can find the details in many books. One that I know of for sure is Jones, [Lebesgue Integration on Euclidean Space](https://www.amazon.com/Lebesgue-Integration-Euclidean-Bartlett-Mathematics/dp/0763717088). Another is Stein and Shakarchi, [Real Analysis](https://www.amazon.com/Real-Analysis-Integration-Princeton-Lectures/dp/0691113866)